# Task Scheduler: Run a Java program after a Python script finishes

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I need to do two things every 10 mins or so:

1) Run a python script

2) Once the above script finishes to completion, run the Java program (JAR file)

I'm using Windows Task scheduler for this. I've come across these two links:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

but I'm just not sure how to go ahead with this. Can I write some powershell script or something which can take care of this? Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with a powershell script. You can execute a programm and then wait until it has finished its taks like this:

```
While($True)
{

Start-Process $PythonPath -Wait

Start-Process $JavaPath -Wait

Start-Sleep -m 10

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in a background task you can define several actions that would be processed one after the other. So I would just create a background task in the Windows Task Scheduler, set the trigger and create two actions, first your python script and then the execution of your java program. Unless the python script returns before it is completed, your two actions will be processed in sequence.